# ALV Column Text and Color won't change

Tags: abap, display, alv

I got a SAP ALV problem.
I want to change the text and the color of a column.
It works if I call the column directly ('BONUS') but when I
use it within a DO-clause and concatenate the name of the column it won't work
for some reason.
Though the column is found and the attributes are changed, at least this is what I see in while debugging.

I hope someone can help me out here.

The following is a part of my coding where the attributes should be changed.

```
        Data: Count Type i.
  DATA: h_fieldname TYPE char30.
  DATA: col_s         TYPE scrtext_s.

  DATA: col_m         TYPE scrtext_m.

  DATA: col_l         TYPE scrtext_l.

  DATA: colname(30) TYPE c.

DATA: lr_functions TYPE REF TO cl_salv_functions_list.

 DATA: gr_columns    TYPE REF TO cl_salv_columns_table.

 DATA: gr_column     TYPE REF TO cl_salv_column_table.

DATA: alv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.

  lv_color_red-col = 7.
  lv_color_red-int = 1.
  lv_color_red-inv = 0.

  lv_color_blue-col = 4.
  lv_color_blue-int = 1.
  lv_color_blue-inv = 0.

  lv_color_green-col = 5.
  lv_color_green-int = 1.
  lv_color_green-inv = 0.
            DO gv_row_count TIMES.

          ADD 1 TO count.
          new = count.

          CLEAR: h_fieldname, colname.
          CONCATENATE 'JAHR' new 'P' INTO h_fieldname.
          CONCATENATE 'Jahr' new INTO colname.
          col_s = colname.
          col_m = colname.
          col_l = colname.
          gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( h_fieldname ).
          gr_column->set_short_text( col_s ).
          gr_column->set_medium_text( col_m ).
          gr_column->set_long_text( col_l ).
          gr_column->set_color( lv_color_blue ).

          CLEAR: h_fieldname, colname.
          CONCATENATE 'JAHR' new 'W' INTO h_fieldname.
          CONCATENATE 'Jahr' new INTO colname.
          col_s = colname.
          col_m = colname.
          col_l = colname.
          gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( h_fieldname ).
          gr_column->set_short_text( col_s ).
          gr_column->set_medium_text( col_m ).
          gr_column->set_long_text( col_l ).
        ENDDO.
```

I'm posting the code of both methods. The first one is building a fieldcatalog an creating a global table so the fieldcatalog could be used in the second method. This one should fill the fieldcatalog, configure the ALV (like column texts and colors) and display the result.

```
EDIT: Here are also the attributes etc. used inside the methods:
  data GT_DATATAB type ref to DATA .
  class ZCL_BONUS_PROCESSING definition load .
  data GT_STANDARD type ZCL_BONUS_PROCESSING=>TTY_FINAL_STANDARD .
  data GT_ADVANCED type ZCL_BONUS_PROCESSING=>TTY_FINAL_ADVANCED .
  data GV_ROW_COUNT type I .


METHOD build_fieldcatalog.

  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <t_itab> TYPE table.
  DATA: t_fieldcat  TYPE lvc_t_fcat.
  DATA: s_fieldcat  TYPE LINE OF lvc_t_fcat.
  DATA: count TYPE i.
*  DATA: new(2) TYPE c.
  DATA: new TYPE string.
  DATA: final_count TYPE i.
  DATA: h_fieldname TYPE char30.

  " Personalnummer
  CLEAR: s_fieldcat.
  s_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'PERNR'.
  s_fieldcat-ref_table  = 'P0000'.
  s_fieldcat-ref_field  = 'PERNR'.
  s_fieldcat-key        = 'X'.
  APPEND s_fieldcat TO t_fieldcat.

  " Zielbonus
  CLEAR: s_fieldcat.
  s_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'BONUS'.
  s_fieldcat-inttype = 'C'.
  s_fieldcat-outputlen = '15'.
*  s_fieldcat-ref_table  = 'P0014'.
*  s_fieldcat-ref_field  = 'YY_BETRAG'.
  s_fieldcat-key        = 'X'.
  APPEND s_fieldcat TO t_fieldcat.

  " Bonusanspruch
  CLEAR: s_fieldcat.
  s_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'BONAN'.
  s_fieldcat-inttype = 'C'.
  s_fieldcat-outputlen = '15'.
*  s_fieldcat-ref_table  = 'P0014'.
*  s_fieldcat-ref_field  = 'YY_BETRAG'.
  s_fieldcat-key        = ''.
  APPEND s_fieldcat TO t_fieldcat.

  " Anspruch
  CLEAR: s_fieldcat.
  s_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'ANSPR'.
*  s_fieldcat-ref_table  = 'P0008'.
*  s_fieldcat-ref_field  = 'TRFGR'.
  s_fieldcat-inttype = 'C'.
  s_fieldcat-outputlen = '1'.
  s_fieldcat-key        = ''.
  APPEND s_fieldcat TO t_fieldcat.

  " Sonderregelung
  CLEAR: s_fieldcat.
  s_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'SONDE'.
  s_fieldcat-inttype    = 'I'.
  s_fieldcat-outputlen  = '1'.
  s_fieldcat-key        = ''.
  APPEND s_fieldcat TO t_fieldcat.

  " Kommentar
  CLEAR: s_fieldcat.
  s_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'COMM'.
  s_fieldcat-inttype    = 'C'.
  s_fieldcat-outputlen  = '50'.
  s_fieldcat-key        = ''.
  APPEND s_fieldcat TO t_fieldcat.

  " Mitarbeiterkreis
  CLEAR: s_fieldcat.
  s_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'PERSK'.
  s_fieldcat-ref_table  = 'P0001'.
  s_fieldcat-ref_field  = 'PERSK'.
  s_fieldcat-key        = 'X'.
  APPEND s_fieldcat TO t_fieldcat.

  count = 0.

  DO gv_row_count TIMES.

    ADD 1 TO count.
    new = count.

    " Lohnart (Jahr) Prozent
    CLEAR: h_fieldname.
    CONCATENATE 'JAHRP' new INTO h_fieldname.
    CONDENSE h_fieldname NO-GAPS.
    CLEAR: s_fieldcat.
    s_fieldcat-fieldname  = h_fieldname.
*    s_fieldcat-ref_table  = 'PZI02'.
*    s_fieldcat-ref_field  = 'ANZHL'.
    s_fieldcat-inttype    = 'C'.
    s_fieldcat-outputlen  = '15'.
    s_fieldcat-coltext    = h_fieldname.
    s_fieldcat-seltext    = h_fieldname.
    s_fieldcat-key        = ''.
    APPEND s_fieldcat TO t_fieldcat.

    " Lohnart (Jahr) Währung
    CLEAR: h_fieldname.
    CONCATENATE 'JAHRW' new INTO h_fieldname.
    CONDENSE h_fieldname NO-GAPS.
    CLEAR: s_fieldcat.
    s_fieldcat-fieldname  = h_fieldname.
*    s_fieldcat-ref_table  = 'P0014'.
*    s_fieldcat-ref_field  = 'YY_BETRAG'.
    s_fieldcat-inttype    = 'C'.
    s_fieldcat-outputlen  = '15'.
    s_fieldcat-coltext    = h_fieldname.
    s_fieldcat-seltext    = h_fieldname.
    s_fieldcat-key        = ''.
    APPEND s_fieldcat TO t_fieldcat.

  ENDDO.

  " Probezeit
  CLEAR: s_fieldcat.
  s_fieldcat-fieldname  = 'PROBE'.
  s_fieldcat-inttype    = 'D'.
  s_fieldcat-outputlen  = '10'.
  s_fieldcat-key        = ''.
  s_fieldcat-col_opt    = 'X'.
  APPEND s_fieldcat TO t_fieldcat.

* Datentabelle aus Feldkatalog erstellen
  CALL METHOD cl_alv_table_create=>create_dynamic_table
    EXPORTING
      it_fieldcatalog = t_fieldcat
    IMPORTING
      ep_table        = gt_datatab.

ENDMETHOD.


METHOD fill_and_display_alv.

  DATA: lstab     TYPE REF TO data.
  DATA: lv_offset TYPE i.
  DATA: dat       TYPE begda.
*  DATA: new(2) TYPE c.
  DATA: new TYPE string.
  DATA: count TYPE i.
  DATA: h_fieldname TYPE char30.
  DATA: col_s         TYPE scrtext_s.
  DATA: col_m         TYPE scrtext_m.
  DATA: col_l         TYPE scrtext_l.
  DATA: colname TYPE char30.
  DATA: lr_functions TYPE REF TO cl_salv_functions_list.
  DATA: gr_columns    TYPE REF TO cl_salv_columns_table.
  DATA: gr_column     TYPE REF TO cl_salv_column_table.
  DATA: alv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.
  DATA: exc TYPE REF TO cx_salv_msg.
*  DATA: t_standard TYPE TABLE OF sty_standard.
  DATA: s_standard TYPE zcl_bonus_data_collect=>sty_final_standard.
*  DATA: t_advanced TYPE TABLE OF sty_advanced.
  DATA: s_advanced TYPE zcl_bonus_data_collect=>sty_final_advanced.

  DATA: lv_color_red TYPE lvc_s_colo.
  DATA: lv_color_blue TYPE lvc_s_colo.
  DATA: lv_color_green TYPE lvc_s_colo.

  lv_color_red-col = 7.
  lv_color_red-int = 1.
  lv_color_red-inv = 0.

  lv_color_blue-col = 4.
  lv_color_blue-int = 1.
  lv_color_blue-inv = 0.

  lv_color_green-col = 5.
  lv_color_green-int = 1.
  lv_color_green-inv = 0.

  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <ls_itab> TYPE ANY,
                 <ls_comp> TYPE ANY.
  FIELD-SYMBOLS: <t_itab> TYPE table.


* Datentabelle füllen
  ASSIGN gt_datatab->* TO <t_itab>.
  cl_salv_table=>factory( IMPORTING r_salv_table = alv  CHANGING t_table = <t_itab> ).

* Zeilenstruktur erzeugen
  CREATE DATA lstab LIKE LINE OF <t_itab>.
  ASSIGN lstab->* TO <ls_itab>.

  LOOP AT gt_standard INTO s_standard.

    CLEAR: s_advanced, <ls_itab>.

    " Personalnummer
    lv_offset = 1.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT lv_offset OF STRUCTURE <ls_itab> TO <ls_comp>.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      <ls_comp> = s_standard-pernr.
    ENDIF.

    " Zielbonus
    lv_offset = 2.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT lv_offset OF STRUCTURE <ls_itab> TO <ls_comp>.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      <ls_comp> = s_standard-ziel_bonus.
    ENDIF.

    " Höhe des Anspruchs auf Zielbonus
    lv_offset = 3.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT lv_offset OF STRUCTURE <ls_itab> TO <ls_comp>.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      <ls_comp> = s_standard-ziel_bonus_anspruch.
    ENDIF.

    " Anspruch
    lv_offset = 4.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT lv_offset OF STRUCTURE <ls_itab> TO <ls_comp>.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      <ls_comp> = s_standard-anspruch.
    ENDIF.

    " Sonderregelung
    lv_offset = 5.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT lv_offset OF STRUCTURE <ls_itab> TO <ls_comp>.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      <ls_comp> = s_standard-sonderreg.
    ENDIF.

    " Kommentar
    lv_offset = 6.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT lv_offset OF STRUCTURE <ls_itab> TO <ls_comp>.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      <ls_comp> = s_standard-comm.
    ENDIF.

    " Mitarbeiterkreis
    lv_offset = 7.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT lv_offset OF STRUCTURE <ls_itab> TO <ls_comp>.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      <ls_comp> = s_standard-persk.
    ENDIF.

    " Beginn Zeitintervalle
    LOOP AT gt_advanced INTO s_advanced WHERE pernr = s_standard-pernr.

      ADD 1 TO lv_offset.

      " Beschäftigungsgrad
      ASSIGN COMPONENT lv_offset OF STRUCTURE <ls_itab> TO <ls_comp>.
      IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
        <ls_comp> = s_advanced-year_percent.
      ENDIF.

      ADD 1 TO lv_offset.

      " Bonuswert (Basiswert)
      ASSIGN COMPONENT lv_offset OF STRUCTURE <ls_itab> TO <ls_comp>.
      IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
        <ls_comp> = s_advanced-year_quantity.
      ENDIF.

    ENDLOOP.

    lv_offset = gv_row_count * 2 + 7.


    ADD 1 TO lv_offset.

    " Probezeit
    ASSIGN COMPONENT lv_offset OF STRUCTURE <ls_itab> TO <ls_comp>.
    IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
      <ls_comp> = s_standard-probez.
    ENDIF.

    ADD 1 TO lv_offset.

* Struktur dem Feldkatalog übergeben
    APPEND <ls_itab> TO <t_itab>.

    TRY .

** Funktionsleiste
        lr_functions = alv->get_functions( ).
        lr_functions->set_all( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>true ).
        lr_functions->set_print( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>true ).

** Optimierung der Spaltengröße
        gr_columns = alv->get_columns( ).
        gr_columns->set_optimize( abap_true ).


        count = 0.
        DO gv_row_count TIMES.

          ADD 1 TO count.
          new = count.

          CLEAR: h_fieldname, colname.
          CONCATENATE 'JAHRP' new INTO h_fieldname.
          CONDENSE h_fieldname NO-GAPS.
          CONCATENATE 'Jahr' new INTO colname.
          CONDENSE colname NO-GAPS.
          col_s = colname.
          col_m = colname.
          col_l = colname.
          gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( columnname = h_fieldname ).
          gr_column->set_short_text( col_s ).
          gr_column->set_medium_text( col_m ).
          gr_column->set_long_text( col_l ).
          gr_column->set_color( lv_color_blue ).

          CLEAR: h_fieldname, colname.
          CONCATENATE 'JAHRW' new INTO h_fieldname.
          CONDENSE h_fieldname NO-GAPS.
          CONCATENATE 'Jahr' new INTO colname.
          CONDENSE colname NO-GAPS.
          col_s = colname.
          col_m = colname.
          col_l = colname.
          gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( columnname = h_fieldname ).
          gr_column->set_short_text( col_s ).
          gr_column->set_medium_text( col_m ).
          gr_column->set_long_text( col_l ).
        ENDDO.

      CATCH cx_salv_msg INTO exc.
        MESSAGE exc TYPE 'I' DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.

    ENDTRY.

  ENDLOOP.

  cl_salv_table=>factory( IMPORTING r_salv_table = alv  CHANGING t_table = <t_itab> ).

* Funktionsleiste
  lr_functions = alv->get_functions( ).
  lr_functions->set_all( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>true ).
  lr_functions->set_print( if_salv_c_bool_sap=>true ).

* Optimierung der Spaltengröße
  gr_columns = alv->get_columns( ).
  gr_columns->set_optimize( abap_true ).

* Titel
  gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( 'BONUS' ).
  gr_column->set_short_text( 'Zielbonus' ).
  gr_column->set_medium_text( 'Zielbonus' ).
  gr_column->set_long_text( 'Aliq. Zielbonus' ).
  gr_column->set_color( lv_color_red ).

  gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( 'BONAN' ).
  gr_column->set_short_text( 'B.anspruch' ).
  gr_column->set_medium_text( 'Bonusanspruch' ).
  gr_column->set_long_text( 'Bonusanspruch' ).

  gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( 'ANSPR' ).
  gr_column->set_short_text( 'Anspruch' ).
  gr_column->set_medium_text( 'Anspruch' ).
  gr_column->set_long_text( 'Anspruch' ).

  gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( 'SONDE' ).
  gr_column->set_short_text( 'Sond.reg.' ).
  gr_column->set_medium_text( 'Sonderregel.' ).
  gr_column->set_long_text( 'Sonderregelung' ).

  gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( 'COMM' ).
  gr_column->set_short_text( 'Komm.' ).
  gr_column->set_medium_text( 'Kommentar' ).
  gr_column->set_long_text( 'Kommentar' ).

  gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( 'PROBE' ).
  gr_column->set_short_text( 'Probez.' ).
  gr_column->set_medium_text( 'Probezeit' ).
  gr_column->set_long_text( 'Probezeit' ).
  gr_column->set_color( lv_color_green ).


  alv->display( ).

ENDMETHOD.
```

Comment: Just tried to set the attribute 'coltext' in the fieldcatalog. But that didn't help as well.

Comment: The code sample is incomplete - at least the declaration of `new` is missing. Also, what are the expected column names?

Comment: Hey, sorry I tried to keep it compact here. The `new` attribute is a char(2). The expected column names are `Jahr1P` `Jahr2P` and so on. Like I said in Debugging I see that the columns are found. Also there is no dump. But the changes do not apply in the ALV for some reason. I'm missing something. I'm about to check everything from the beginning. Starting with the fieldcatalog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... you did not specify the type of the variable `new` but I will assume it is `STRING`. If it is then making such an assignment

```
new = count.
```

will not get rid of the space at the end of the `count` variable.

This simple program shows it.

```
REPORT ZZZ.

DATA: gv_row_count TYPE i VALUE 30.
DATA: fieldname TYPE char30.
DATA: new TYPE string.

START-OF-SELECTION.
   new = gv_row_count.
   CONCATENATE 'JAHR' new 'P' INTO fieldname.
   WRITE fieldname.
```

The output is `JAHR30 P` and not `JAHR30P`.

To work around it you can put the following statement after the `CONCATENATE` one.

```
CONDENSE h_fieldname NO-GAPS.
```

or even neater just use string templates instead of concatenating then you will not need the variable `new`.

```
h_fieldname = |JAHR{ count }P|.
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I just tried to use the `CONDENSE` statement. The `new` attribute was a char(2) but I changed it to string to test both variants. Unfortunately it didn't work. It's kind of weird because the columns are found. Otherwise there would be a dump. And in Debugging it seems to work. But the changes are not displayed. But it's only with These columns where I concatenate the names. So I'm going to keep searching for an error which maybe occures here.

Comment: Changing the column with a hardcoded column name `JAHR1P` worked. But that's not the solution I'm looking for because the amount of columns and so there names are dynamically.

Comment: I am happy to help but you need to post more code. Do you display the data of an SAP Table or some kind of a custom one in your ALV?

Comment: I just posted another answer so I could post the whole code of those two methods where the fieldcatalog is build and filled. Hope this makes it more clear where the error occures. I'm displaying the data of two custom tables. One has a fixed count of columns and the other one is flexible in how many columns it has. Thanks and kinds regards.

Comment: I just tried to run the report. Same result as before with wrong colors and stuff. Then I copied the `LOOP` which sets the column names and colors and pasted it beneath the hard coded attribute changes (Like: `gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( 'BONUS' ).`) 
For some reason after this change it worked. I just tried to reset the change to be sure this change was the solution but the report still worked. I'm not really sure what happend but it currently works fine. Now I try to find out what exactly changed that the report now works. Thanks for your help anyway! :)

Comment: @Dyrdek If you are happy with my answer, please mark it as accepted as well. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for one column, there's no reason that it doesn't with another one.

Do as usual to troubleshoot your code. Make sure that the column name is well written, and is the name of an existing column in the ALV table.

Comment: I already did this but I'm going over it again. Thanks for the reply! I think something doesn't work with the `COCATENATE`. The columns will be found but aren't changed.

Comment: It's easy to find whether something is wrong with `CONCATENATE` by using the debugger. But you say "columns will be found", so you did debug and made sure that your `CONCATENATE` is okay. I propose to continue the discussion in Jagger's one.